# Skipping chunk X of Y.Z because MySQL chose no index instead of the word_sid_typeindex

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.1, percona-toolkit, pt-table-checksum

My environment:

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)
# uname -a
Linux A.B.C 2.6.32-642.4.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Aug 15 02:06:41 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -q mysql-server percona-toolkit
mysql-server-5.1.73-7.el6.x86_64
percona-toolkit-2.2.19-1.noarch
#
```

I'm running `pt-table-checksum` and I'm getting following error:

> Skipping chunk X of Y.Z because MySQL chose no index instead of the
>   word_sid_typeindex.

```
mysql> DESCRIBE search_index;
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| word  | varchar(50)      | NO   | MUL |         |       |
| sid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |       |
| type  | varchar(16)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| score | float            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name='search_index'\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: search_index
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 3155432
 Avg_row_length: 51
    Data_length: 163250176
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 415514624
      Data_free: 839909376
 Auto_increment: NULL
    Create_time: 2016-09-01 21:14:58
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment: 
1 row in set (0.13 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified

mysql>
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

The message is both expected and disturbing.

## WHY EXPECTED ?

I don't find this message disturbing at all. I would expect [pt-table-checksum](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-checksum.html) to bypass chunks since there is no defined uniqueness. Granted, InnoDB will create a [row-based index called gen_clust_index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-index-types.html) when there is no PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE INDEX. So, chunks read from the table have no rhyme or reason to its order other than order of insertion.

## WHY DISTURBING ?

Since you have a replication tag on the question, now this becomes disturbing.

When you have many writes on a master, the slave may write rows in a different order than the master. If the `search_index` table had a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE INDEX`, that would stabilize checksum evaluation. Unfortunately, that cannot be said in the case of a table that has an internally generated index (gen_clust_index) as the only form of uniqueness with an InnoDB table ON BOTH MASTER AND SLAVE.

## SOLUTION

1. Define a PRIMARY KEY for `search index`on the Master.
2. mysqldump `search_index` from the Master and load it into the Slave

Answer (score 1):

This is what I'd suggest:

- run `SHOW INDEXES FROM Y.Z\G`
- use the index with the highest Cardinality in `--chunk-index` option
- use a different hash function `--function=md5`
- use a smaller `--chunk-size` (eg. 200)

Optionally, run ANALYZE TABLE on the affected table to re-calculate its statistics. Make sure you're aware of the effects of running ANALYZE TABLE on a busy server.